# AlpineJs, adding dynamic id to element and comparing on mouseover event

Tags: javascript, laravel, alpine.js

I want to display some data beloning to an image when a user hovers over it, how would I go adding and comparing id's from a livewire component ?

Livewire view

```php
<div x-data="{tooltip : false}" class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 ml-2 antialiased text-gray-900">
    <div @mouseover.away="{tooltip = false}">
        @forelse($animals as $animal)
            <img id="{{$animal->animals->id}}" x-on:mouseover="{tooltip = !tooltip}"
                 src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/350x350"
                 alt="Animal image"
                 class="object-cover rounded-lg shadow-md ">

            <div x-show.transition="tooltip" class="absolute -mt-16 ">
                <div class="p-6 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg">
                    <h4 class="mt-1 text-xl font-semibold leading-tight uppercase truncate">This is
                        : {{$animal->animals->name}}</h4>
                    <div class="mt-4">
                        <span class="font-semibold text-teal-600 text-md">4/5 ratings </span>
                        <span class="text-sm text-gray-600">(based on 234 ratings)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @empty
            <p class="text-center">No animals found</p>
        @endforelse
    </div>
</div>
```

Livewire class

```
class Dashboard extends Component
{

    public function render()
    {
        $animal = UserAnimal::with('animals')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->get();

        return view('livewire.dashboard')->with('animals', $animal);
    }
}
```

This snippet works when only one image is displayed, but as soon as another image is added the tooltip stops working,

E.g the user hovers over the first image and the name of that animal is displayed in the hovering tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a global `tooltip` attribute on the parent div, I would use a `tooltip` attribute for each animal - which means you probably need to adjust your loop and html structure.

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 ml-2 antialiased text-gray-900">
    <div x-data="{tooltip : false}">
      <img id="{{$animal->animals->id}}" x-on:mouseover="{tooltip = !tooltip}" x-on:mouseout="{tooltip = !tooltip}" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/350x350" alt="Animal image" class="object-cover rounded-lg shadow-md ">
      <div x-show.transition="tooltip" class="absolute -mt-16 ">
        <div class="p-6 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg">
          <h4 class="mt-1 text-xl font-semibold leading-tight uppercase truncate">This is
            : A dog</h4>
          <div class="mt-4">
            <span class="font-semibold text-teal-600 text-md">4/5 ratings </span>
            <span class="text-sm text-gray-600">(based on 234 ratings)</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div x-data="{tooltip : false}">
      <img id="{{$animal->animals->id}}" x-on:mouseover="{tooltip = !tooltip}" x-on:mouseout="{tooltip = !tooltip}" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/350x350" alt="Animal image" class="object-cover rounded-lg shadow-md ">
      <div x-show.transition="tooltip" class="absolute -mt-16 ">
        <div class="p-6 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg">
          <h4 class="mt-1 text-xl font-semibold leading-tight uppercase truncate">This is
            : A cat</h4>
          <div class="mt-4">
            <span class="font-semibold text-teal-600 text-md">1/5 ratings </span>
            <span class="text-sm text-gray-600">(based on 2 ratings)</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Example in Codepen](https://codepen.io/codedge/pen/XWNayOY)

Comment: Fixed my loop and html based on your answer, and that fixed it. Thank you ! spend so long on this but seems it was much easier then I thought.